# Im trying to plot some words and I'm getting the warning that some words could not be fit on page. How can I make them fit in?

Tags: r, word-cloud

```
#I tried this, but Null kept popping up

dev.new(width = 1000, height = 1000, unit = "in") 
wordcloud(NoEvaluables3,max.words =25,random.order = T,colors = brewer.pal(name = "Dark2", n = 8))
```

Comment: What package does wordcloud come from?

Comment: It comes from wordcloud

Comment: Make a [reprex]. Then people will be able to copy-paste your problem into R and try out ways to fix your problem.